# ionic / AngularJS - put method return error 400 (bad request) - [ object Object ]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

i have a simple Web API and `ionic/angularJs` Client for `CRUD` operations. when i send data for edit on the server and i'll get an error.

this is picture of the send data format and error :

[image: Error]

angularJS method for update

```
$scope.save = function (location) {
        var obj = {
            //locationId: $scope.id,
            locationName: location.locationName,
            locationDescription: location.locationDescription
        };

        console.log('output: ' + JSON.stringify(obj));
        $http.put(ServerPath + "/" + $scope.id, $scope.id, obj).success(function (data) {

            $state.go('tab.home');
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An error has occured while adding! " + data;
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
    };
```

Comment: please include source code

Comment: @RubenYeghikyan i added the angularJS method

Comment: make sure you're parsing data that your server accepts. try to use web tool or http plugin to see headers. try to modify your request and resend it.

Comment: @RubenYeghikyan thanks, i'd like to say I tested my project in pure angularjs and its will fine and has no any error. but when i want use this code in Ionic project its not work. and i wonder how add or delete action workes fine but only edit/update function has an error !

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code and its worked..

```
$scope.save = function (location) {

        var obj = {
            locationId: $scope.id,
            locationName: location.locationName,
            locationDescription: location.locationDescription
        };

        $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: ServerPath + "/" + $scope.id,
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $state.go('tab.home');
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('Error: ' + status);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When I made a demonstration with $http&$resource&postman to issue a PUT request, I received the message below:

```
ionic.bundle.js:23826 PUT http://localhost:8100/api/users/1?access_token=97d3258a-5a4e-4af4-bd87-3bb9bbb0039f 400 (Bad Request)
```

A few days' googling and many experiments later, I found out the reason that because my bean class was defined as below:

```java
class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public User(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Once I remove the constructor's definition or add a non-parameter constructor, it works well.